# Implementing a custom reducer using ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I know that Ramda.js provides a reduce function, but I am trying to learn how to use ramda and I thought a reducer would be a good example. Given the following code, what would be a more efficient and functional approach?

```js
(function(){

  // Some operators. Sum and multiplication.
  const sum = (a, b) => a + b;
  const mult = (a, b) => a * b;

  // The reduce function
  const reduce = R.curry((fn, accum, list) => {
    const op = R.curry(fn);
    while(list.length > 0){
      accum = pipe(R.head, op(accum))(list);
      list = R.drop(1, list);
    }
    return accum;
  });

  const reduceBySum = reduce(sum, 0);
  const reduceByMult = reduce(mult, 1);

  const data = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  const result1 = reduceBySum(data);
  const result2 = reduceByMult(data);

  console.log(result1); // 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 => 10
  console.log(result2); // 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 => 24

})();
```

Run this on the REPL: http://ramdajs.com/repl/

Comment: Are there special cases you want to handle that won't work for `const reduce = R.curry((fn, accum, list) => list.reduce(fn, accum));` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a learning exercise and not for real-world application.  Correct?

There are certainly some efficiencies you could gain over that code.  At the core of Ramda's implementation, when all the dispatching, transducing, etc. are stripped away, is something like:

```
const reduce = curry(function _reduce(fn, acc, list) {
  var idx = 0;
  while (idx < list.length) {
    acc = fn(acc, list[idx]);
    idx += 1;
  }
  return acc;
});
```

I haven't tested, but this probably gains on your version because it only uses the number of functions calls strictly needed: one for each member of the list, and it does that with bare-bones iteration.  Your version adds the call to `curry`, and then, on each iteration, calls to `pipe` and `head`, to that curried `op` function, to the result of the `pipe` call, and to `drop`.  So this one should be faster.

On the other hand, this code is as imperative as it gets.  If you want to go with something more purely functional, you would need to use a recursive solution.  Here's one version:

```
const reduce = curry(function _reduce(fn, acc, list) {
  return (list.length) ? _reduce(fn, fn(acc, head(list)), tail(list)) : acc;
});
```

This sacrifices all the performance of the above to the calls to `tail`.  But it's clearly more of a straightforward functional implementation.  In many modern JS engines, however, this will fail to even work on larger lists due to the stack depth.

Because it is tail-recursive, it would be able to take advantage of tail-call optimization specified by ES2015 but so far little implemented.  Until then, it's mostly of academic interest.  And even when that is available, because of the `head` and -- especially -- `tail` call in there, it's going to be much slower than the imperative implementation above.

You might be interested to know that Ramda was the second attempt at the API that's generated.  Its original authors (disclaimer: I'm one of them) first built [Eweda](https://github.com/CrossEye/eweda) on the lines of this latter version.  That experiment failed for exactly these reasons.  Javascript simply cannot handle this sort of recursion... yet.

Comment: Yep, this was just a learning excercise. Thanks a lot for your extensive and thoughtful response. I was tempted to go the recursive way, but like you said, there is no recursive optimization. Even so, your code sample is very helpful. Thanks again!